# Version history of a SharePoint online term store

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-userprofile

We are having a term store that is linked to the Office Location property of our SharePoint user profile, somehow the term store values was deleted and recreated which had broken the relation in the user profile property and now the Office location property which is tied to that term store is giving error as "Invalid term"
[image]

The Term1 is showing in red as currently it does not exists in term set. So how to get the version history/ logs to understand how this term was updated and by which user.
I tried checking the audit logs didn't got information about the account that did this.
Is there any other way to track this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each site should have a TaxonomyHiddenList of terms which are used in the site.

You might be able to see what happened in the activity panel of that list.
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/YourSite/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/

[image]